# How to mount two windows shared folders in linux?

Tags: mount, opensuse, fstab

I'm using OpenSuse 12.2 x64. I have tried this in `/etc/fstab`:

```
//192.168.6.80/shared/folder1 /mnt/folder1 cifs rw,user=guest,password=,uid=1000 0 0
//192.168.6.80/shared/folder2 /mnt/folder2 cifs rw,user=guest,password=,uid=1000 0 0
```

After rebooting, if I access the first folder `cd /mnt/folder1` and list files `ls`, my shared files are listed. If I try accessing `folder2`, nothing is listed.

If I reboot and try again, but this time accessing `folder2` first, the files are listed. After, accessing `folder1` nothing is listed.

In other words, it mounts just the first accessed folder. Mounting it manually, `mount -all`, the two folders are mounted, but I need it to be mounted automatically at boot because these folders are used in services.

How do I mount more than one shared folder using `/etc/fstab` at boot?

Answer (score 3):

Try modifying your boot options in your commands so they include the `_netdev` option:

```
//192.168.6.80/shared/folder1 /mnt/folder1 cifs _netdev,rw,user=guest,password=,uid=1000 0 0
//192.168.6.80/shared/folder2 /mnt/folder2 cifs _netdev,rw,user=guest,password=,uid=1000 0 0
```

Per this thread that I found titled: [CIFS share in /etc/fstab doesn't automatically mount](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=149039).

#### References

- [MountWindowsSharesPermanently](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MountWindowsSharesPermanently)